# INVALID_USER_CREDENTIALS/JSON_EXCEPTION in "PayU" Android Integration

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payu

I am tring to integrate payU payment gateway with my ecommerce application. I have a account on [test payU](https://test.payumoney.com/) with merchant id, key and salt.

I am working on this [demo application](https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK-Sample-App), whenever i change parameters like `merchant key`, `salt`. I get a `error code 5014`.

Which can be either of them.

- **`int INVALID_USER_CREDENTIALS = 5014;`**
- **`int JSON_EXCEPTION = 5014;`**

> > **Note**:  I am getting this as a `response string`:
>
> **`"Something went wrong : Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"`**

I am trying to debug it.But am unable to find a proper documentation.

Please help.

Comment: I  also get same error some one please try to help me

Comment: Btw the problem may be because of your account might not be activated drop them a mail they will activate you account

Comment: @Shubham: Are you sure about, account not be activated....?

Comment: I am pretty sure as int INVALID_USER_CREDENTIALS = 5014.

Comment: @Shubham: I also get this error when run the demo code in my app with changes key and salt.

Comment: @Jayesh try latest sdk https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK-Sample-App/tree/version/sdk4.3.6cb6mr1.0.4\

Comment: I am already using that code.

Comment: i am using gtKFFx/eCwWELxi merchant id and key value pair and it's work

Comment: if you are having Something went wrong : Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject that means you are passing wrong params either your hashes are not correct/environment or config object is wrong

Comment: does anyone find the solution..i am also getting the same error...

Answer (score -1):

From the Payu Documentation,

This error occurs when merchant uses any of the following incorrectly.

- Wrong Key
- Wrong Salt
- Wrong Environment

**Please note that ENVIRONMENT should be 1 for test credentials and 0 for live credentials**

Solution: Please make sure the test key being used if you are hitting the test environment and vice-versa.